# IBM Cloud Functions: How to install "ibm_db" for serverless Db2 access in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I got simple node.js code that works ok on my laptop. This testing nodejs application just selects a row from a Db2 database in IBM Cloud. However, when I integrated the code and deploy to IBM cloud, it complains "Error during initialization: { Error: Cannot find module 'connect:db2'( or ibm_db )".

I think that the environment in IBM Cloud does not have the ibm_db installed, My question is   what are steps to install ibm_db to IBM Cloud to get the application (actually it is an action of a package in IBM Cloud) working?

Answer (score 0):

The [ibm_db package is part of several runtimes of IBM Cloud Functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-runtimes#openwhisk_ref_javascript_environments). For Node.js with Db2 I recommend to use the Node 8 or Node 10 runtimes. You need to specify the version when you create the action.

The [solution tutorial on how to build a database-driven Slack chatbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#build-a-database-driven-slackbot) uses Cloud Functions to access Db2. The code is written in Node.js and available on GitHub with instructions on how to deploy it. See the link.